# Google Calendar (Apps) popping up 2 alerts for each event

Tags: google-calendar

For my event reminders, Google Calendar insists on giving me two dialog boxes.  I can disable events reminders altogether, but really would like to have just the one.

I am using Fluid 1.6.1 on OS X with local cookie storage.

I sync my calendar with Mac's calendar app, and it shows me each alert just one time.